# What is the logic behind Html.DisplayNameFor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Today I'm noticed strange behavior in scaffolded razor views, which have `IEnumerable<Item>` model.

Even if model is a `IEnumerable` it's use single item notation for the table header

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        ... 
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr> ... </tr>
    }
...
```

How it's itself 'unpack' collection to a single items and if it's so clever, what else it could do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using this overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

(see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7BSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7B</code>0%7D%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D%29))

You can use the extension method on an `IEnumerable<T>`, while the lambda uses just the `T` to get at the property.

Comment: ah, thanks, I see. So if it's will be ICollection instead of IEnumerable it will not working, right?

Comment: [`ICollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) extends the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, so that should still work.